# How to query MS SQL Server using PHP and not list column names?

Tags: php, sql-server, html, web

I am using PHP to query a Microsoft SQL Server and returning the result set. My issue is the PHP code returns the result set that I want, however it is only a partial result set.

The full table has **6** columns of data for this example

**Below is the code snippet of the table design in the Database in an HTML Snippet:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>COL1</td>
    <td>COL2</td>  
    <td>COL3</td>
    <td>COL4</td>
    <td>COL5</td>  
    <td>COL6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>rowdata</td>
    <td>rowdata</td>  
    <td>rowdata</td>
<td>rowdata</td>
    <td>rowdata</td>  
    <td>rowdata</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>rowdata</td>
    <td>rowdata</td>  
    <td>rowdata</td>
<td>John</td>
    <td>rowdata</td>  
    <td>rowdata</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

**Below is the PHP Script used to query the SQL Server:**

```
<?php    

$serverName = "sqlserver";   
$uid = "username";     
$pwd = "password";    
$databaseName = "databasename";   

$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,                              
                         "PWD"=>$pwd,                              
                         "Database"=>$databaseName);   


/* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */    
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo); 

$tsql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE " ;  


/* Execute the query. */    

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);  


if ( $stmt )    
{    
     echo "Statement executed.<br>\n";    
}     
else     
{    
     echo "Error in statement execution.\n";    
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));    
}    


    //Working Query
/* Iterate through the result set printing a row of data upon each iteration. */

  while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
 foreach ($row as $column=>$value)


   {
      echo 
       $column.": " .$value."<br />";

   }
   echo '<hr />';

}





/* Free statement and connection resources. */    
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);    
sqlsrv_close( $conn);    

?>
```

This is the issue only **4** columns are returned and **1** row of data for those **4** columns

**Example of what is returned in PHP Console:**

```
Statement executed.<br>
COL1: rowdata<br />COL2: rowdata<br />COL3: rowdata<br />COL4: rowdata<br />
```

If you cannot already tell, I am attempting to display the full result set of the query without listing the columns in PHP.

I.E.

```
echo $row[1];
echo $row[2];
echo $row[3];
```

etc.

---------------------------------------------------**UPDATE**------------------------------------------------------------

I have found there is an issue with the **DATETIME** Columns in the SQL Server. When I **CAST()** the columns in the SQL Query being passed in the PHP code, it returned the full Result Set. This is a work around, however I would like to retain the **DATETIME** format and just pass a query through instead of Casting it.

Thoughts?

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
/* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */    
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo); 

$tsql = "SELECT
COL1,
COL2,
COL3,
CAST(COL4 AS VARCHAR) 'COL4'
COL5,
COL6  
FROM TABLE " ;
```

**Example of what is returned in PHP Console:**

```
  Statement executed.<br>
    COL1: rowdata<br />COL2: rowdata<br />COL3: rowdata<br />COL4: rowdata<br />COL5: rowdata<br />COL6: rowdata<br />
COL1: rowdata<br />COL2: rowdata<br />COL3: rowdata<br />COL4: rowdata<br />COL5: rowdata<br />COL6: rowdata<br />
```

As you can see it returns the entire result set of the table.

Comment: It seems the limiting of 4 columns being returned also takes place when I echo each column. I am wondering if perhaps there is a limit in the functions that can be returned? Seems like a lot of trouble for what I am trying to do. All I need is a full result set of a SELECT Statement...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to read rows as an associate array.  Try using *sqlsrv_fetch_assoc* instead of *sqlsrv_fetch_array* as you're doing now.

```
//replace the function call in the line below!
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
 foreach ($row as $column=>$value)


   {
      echo 
       $column.": " .$value."<br />";

   }
   echo '<hr />';

}
```

Comment: I do not suppose you could give an example my good man, not sure where I would add this?

Comment: change to sqlsrv_fetch_assoc($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)

Comment: AH i see I have tried that particular change, It just returns the "Statement Execute. <BR> from the IF Statement above.. No data is returned :\

Comment: Updated a comment on my original post, it appears that there is some sort of limit for this particular code. I do not suppose you have some other way of doing this? Attempting to display the full result set of a SELECT * FROM TABLE; column names and rows would probably put it into a function as we are trying to create a Web Report Page similar to an Microsoft Access ADP File with a link to a SQL Server